# C++ templates and functions on lhs

Tags: c++

given the following class:

```
template< class T> class table2D
{
   ...
  public:
   bool  copy(int r, int c, int rows , int cols, table2D & s ) ;
};
```

where, method copy() copies a block or elements from ***s*** to ***this***,

how can I code the above (using templates???) so that I can use the ethod as follows:

```
table2D  s, d ;
d.copy(0, 0, 3, 3) = s ;
```

Comment: You want to make a copy, and then stomp it with another value? I cannot see the purpose here. Declare it as `copy(..., const table2D &s)` and call it `d.copy(..., s)`. Why insist on the LHS?

Comment: of course the obvious way is to do: d.copy(..., s), but there is a way to code d.copy(..) = s ; and have the compiler call d.copy(..., s). I want it similar to "d = s ;" and I have seen it before, so I know it can be done, but don't know haw...

Comment: You could just invent an object that contains a table2D<T>& and 4 `int`s and define d.copy(4 ints) to return that object, then define `operator=` of that object to call the other d.copy

Comment: I'm not even sure what that means, semantically, so I have a hard time understanding how the compiler would. What you're trying to do is completely against the way C++ is intended to function, which is usually a warning that you're doing it the wrong way.

Comment: @JSF I think this invokes the "Just because you can, doesn't mean you should" rule.

Comment: I think the main issue here is that `copy` is not a good description of what the new form of the function does. Perhaps `slice` or `region` would be a better name.

Comment: Also, why `table2D & s` rather than `table2D const& s`?  I copied that questionable detail into my answer, since that wasn't the focus of the question, but that doesn't mean I agree with it.  Eric is right about the name, though that also was not the focus of the question.

Answer (score 3):

I disagree with the comment by tadman enough that I roughed out the code (probably with a few errors, but I think the concepts are right).

I'm sure there are more elegant and general ways to code this.  But I think this kind of thing is very much the way C++ is intended to function.

It is a very standard C++ technique to create a placeholder object to keep the inputs to a function whose true work needs to be done later.

```
template< class T> class copier4i
{
    copier4i(T& t, int a, int b, int c, int d) : m_t(t), m_a(a), m_b(b), m_c(c), m_d(d) {}
    bool operator=(T& s) { return m_t.copy(m_a,m_b,m_c,m_d,s); }
    T& m_t;
    int m_a, m_b, m_c, m_d;
};

...
template< class T> class table2D
{
   ...
  public:
   bool  copy(int r, int c, int rows , int cols, table2D & s ) ;
   copier4i<table2D>  copy(int r, int c, int rows , int cols) {
      return copier4i<table2D>(*this,r,c,rows,cols); }
};
```

I don't have a great place to test this, so I'm not sure whether the extra `<table2D>` I just added above was the correct solution (to what I expected to be deduced) or whether the problem is (something I've never been completely clear on) the name `table2D` used inside its own definition, when does that implicitly mean `table2D<T>` (as I intended here) vs. when does that need to be explicit (as it would if used outside the definition of `table2D`.  So maybe it should be:

```
   auto  copy(int r, int c, int rows , int cols) {
      return copier4i(*this,r,c,rows,cols); }
```

or maybe

```
   copier4i<table2D<T> >  copy(int r, int c, int rows , int cols) {
      return copier4i<table2D<T> >(*this,r,c,rows,cols); }
```

New version, including the change from `bool` to `void` that George T. made, and this time tested at ideone (as C++14 code)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


template< class T > class copier4i
{
  public:
     T&  m_t;
     int m_a, m_b, m_c, m_d;

     copier4i(T& t, int a, int b, int c, int d) : m_t(t), m_a(a), m_b(b), m_c(c), m_d(d) {}
     copier4i& operator=(T& s) { m_t.copy(m_a,m_b,m_c,m_d,s); return *this;}

} ;

template< class T> class table2D
{
   public:
     int m_rows  ;
     int m_cols  ;
     T  * m_obj  ;
   public:
     table2D( int r, int c ) {
        m_rows = r ;
        m_cols = c ;
        m_obj  = ( T * )malloc( m_rows * m_cols * sizeof( T ) ) ;
     }
     ~table2D() {
        free( m_obj );
     }
     inline T *    operator[](int  r) {
        return  (this->m_obj + (r * m_cols ) ) ;
     }
     void  copy( int r, int c, int cr, int cc, table2D &s) {
         (*this)[r][c] = s[0][0]  ;
     }

     copier4i< table2D >  copy(int r, int c, int rows , int cols)
     {
        return copier4i<table2D>( *this, r, c, rows, cols );
     }
} ;


int main()
{

  table2D<int> t(5, 5);
  table2D<int> s(5, 5);

  s.copy(0, 0, 2, 2, t );

  s.copy(0, 0, 2, 2) = t ;
}
```

Comment: I'll give you points for trying. Pretty sure the `operator=` function needs work, those are probably all `m_a` etc.

Comment: The problem here is not so much that C++ can do it, as it surely can, but that `d.copy(...) = x` is so bizarre that it obfuscates what's happening. A more conventional `d.copy(..., x)` is considerably more readable, it's quite clear what's happening.

Comment: I found the original request quite reasonable and a clearer representation of the intent.  We are pretending a function selects part of an object and gives out a reference to that part, then that reference is used on the left side of an `=` to overwrite that part.  Quite natural if the object were easily able to return a reference to the desired part of itself.  Assuming it can't do so, that should be the object's problem, not the consumer's problem.  So if you can't easily return a reference to the desired part of the object, fake it so it appears that you did.

Comment: @JSF maybe applying Eric's comment can help to clarify what this does. Renaming `copy` into `region` would help clear up that you are getting a region and that can be assigned.

Comment: @tadman: It's the name that's bizarre, not the idea; it looks more reasonable if you write `d.submatrix(0,0,3,3) = x;`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help. 
Yes, it may look bizarre but it also has it merit once you get used to.

The code posted does not compile though, and my knowledge about templates it not that great to find the error. Could you please see the bellow:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


template< class T > class copier4i
{
  public:
     T&  m_t;
     int m_a, m_b, m_c, m_d;

     copier4i(T& t, int a, int b, int c, int d) : m_t(t), m_a(a), m_b(b), m_c(c), m_d(d) {}
     bool operator=(T& s) { return m_t.copy(m_a,m_b,m_c,m_d,s); }

} ;

template< class T> class table2D
{
   public:
     int m_rows  ;
     int m_cols  ;
     T  * m_obj  ;
   public:
     table2D( int r, int c ) {
        m_rows = r ;
        m_cols = c ;
        m_obj  = ( T * )malloc( m_rows * m_cols * sizeof( T ) ) ;
     }
     ~table2D() {
        free( m_obj );
     }
     inline T *    operator[](int  r) {
        return  (this->m_obj + (r * m_cols ) ) ;
     }
     void  copy( int r, int c, int cr, int cc, table2D &s) {
         (*this)[r][c] = s[0][0]  ;
     }

     copier4i< table2D >  copy(int r, int c, int rows , int cols)
     {
        return copier4i( *this, r, c, rows, cols );
     }
} ;


void main()
{

  table2D<int> t(5, 5);
  table2D<int> s(5, 5);

  s.copy(0, 0, 2, 2, t );

  s.copy(0, 0, 2, 2) = t ;
}
```

The error is:

```
ttt.cpp
ttt.cpp(40) : error C2955: 'copier4i' : use of class template requires template argument list
        ttt.cpp(6) : see declaration of 'copier4i'
        ttt.cpp(39) : while compiling class template member function 'copier4i<T> table2D<int>::copy(int,int,int,int)'
        with
        [
            T=table2D<int>
        ]
        ttt.cpp(48) : see reference to class template instantiation 'table2D<T>' being compiled
        with
        [
            T=int
        ]
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have a handy place to test that and I thought the template argument was deduced in that usage.  I think the edit I just did to my answer should fix that error (added another `<table2D>` where it seems to be needed).  I still haven't tested.